# Backbone.js + modal window - What is causing this to break on IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, backbone.js

I've got a simple contact management table in backbone.js that uses twitter's bootstrap-modal to present the form input.

Everything seems to work fine in Firefox and Chrome, but the modal will not come up in IE 9 and I'm getting some strange css renderings as well (haven't tried other versions of IE yet).

I've tried using the IE libraries on Google code located here: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

But no luck.

Here's a fiddle for the project if someone could take a peek and see what may be the culprit:
http://jsfiddle.net/phillipkregg/9cvVv/31/

**EDIT:**

Updated Fiddle without trailing commas:  http://jsfiddle.net/phillipkregg/9cvVv/39/

Here is how the file renders just running the code live through my dev environment on IE9:
[image]

I've tried using the various Browser Modes and Document Modes (like quirks mode) through the IE developer tools (F12).  They all render the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

```
saveContact: function() {
    var first = $("#first-name-input").val();
    var last = $("#last-name-input").val();
    var address = $("#address-input").val();
    this.collection.create({
        first_name: first,
        last_name: last,
        address: address // there's your problem ->,
    });
```

Trailing comma, hoses IE every time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Jake - didn't know about trailing commas being a problem.  I went in and updated the fiddle to remove the trailing commas, but the modal still isn't coming up.  Could IE be having issues with the templates or something else? (added the new fiddle uptop).

Comment: It's popping up for me in IE8.  Are you sure it's not working in IE9?